# Poder poner una cadena dentro de un carácter y luego que este retorne a su función y luego imprimirlo en int main

Tags: c, string, funciones, caracteres

Quiero imprimir un caracter pero dentro tiene un string o cadena...
Me sale el error de:

> **125  8 [Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast**

El problema se encuentra casi al ultimo, donde dice:

```
//Funciones para salida de datos
//Salida de suma
```

El código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<math.h>

//Prototipo - Funcion
int suma(int, int);
int resto(int, int);
int multiplicacion(int, int);
float divicion(int, int);
int resio(int, int);
int pote(int, int);
float raiz(int, int);
//Prototipo para salida de datos
char salidaSuma();

//Función Principal
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"spanish");
    
    int n1, n2, potencia, sum, resta, multi, residuo;
    float divi, raz;
    
    n1 = 36;
    n2 = 2;
    printf("\n");

    sum = suma(n1, n2);
    resta = resto(n1, n2);
    multi = multiplicacion(n1, n2);
    divi = divicion(n1, n2);
    residuo = resi(n1, n2);
    potencia = pote(n1, n2);
    raz = raiz(n1, n2);
    
    printf("La suma de los numeros es: %i\n",sum);
    printf("La resta de los numeros es: %i\n",resta);
    printf("La multiplicacion de los numeros es: %i\n",multi);
    printf("La divicion de los numeros es: %.2f\n",divi);
    printf("La residuo de los numeros es: %i\n",residuo);
    printf("La potencia de los numeros es: %i\n",potencia);
    printf("La raiz de los numeros es: %.2f\n",raz);
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("%c %i",salidaSuma(),sum);

    return 0;
}

//Funciones

//1.1 ingresar num1
int ingresarNum1(){
    int num1;
    printf("Ingresar el primer valor: ");
    scanf("%i",&num1);

    return num1;
}

// 1.2 Ingresar num2
int ingresarNum2(){
    int num2;
    printf("Ingresar el segundo valor: ");
    scanf("%f",&num2);
    
    return num2;
}

//2 suma
int suma(int num1, int num2){
    int resultado;
    resultado = num1+num2;
    return resultado;
}

//3 resta
int resto(int num1, int num2){
    int resultado;
    resultado = num1 - num2;
    return resultado;
}

//4 multiplicacion
int multiplicacion(int num1, int num2){
    int resultado;
    resultado = num1 * num2;
    return resultado;
}

//5 divicion
float divicion(int num1, int num2){
    float resultado;
    resultado = num1 / num2*1.0;
    return resultado;
}

//6 residuo
int resi(int num1, int num2){
    int resultado;
    resultado = num1%num2;
    return resultado;
}

//7 potencia
int pote(int num1, int num2){
    int pot;
    pot = pow(num1, num2);
    return pot;
}


//8 raiz
float raiz(int num1, int num2){
    float raz, ind;
    ind = 1.0 / num2;
    raz = pow(num1, ind);
    return raz;
}

//Funciones para salida de datos
//Salida de suma
char salidaSuma(){
    char resul;
    resul = "La suma de los numeros es: ";
    return resul;
}
```

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. Y los literal de cadena son de tipo `char*`.  Por lo que deberías corregir el tipo de retorno de la función.

Comment: lo que veo es que quieres guardar un string( cadena de varios caracteres ) en un char que solo podes guardar una sola letra o caracter
opciones o cambias char result por algún vector para poder contener tantas letras (char) en la linea 124
otra opcion seria obviar la linea 130 resul = "La suma de los numeros es: "; y directamente mostrar por medio de un scanf en el return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un tipo `char` únicamente puede almacenar un caracter, ya que una variable de este tipo ocupará únicamente 1 byte, lo que le permite almacenar 256 valores diferentes.

Para gestionar cadenas de caracteres necesitas un puntero a `char`:

```
char const * salidaSuma()
{
    char const * resul;
    resul = "La suma de los numeros es: ";
    return resul;
}
```

Por otro lado, el código que imprime la salida de esta función también está mal, ya que lo que vas a imprimir es una cadena de caracteres:

```
printf("%s %i",salidaSuma(),sum);
```

Aun así, esta función carece totalmente de sentido y utilidad. No aporta ningún tipo de mejora o ventaja respecto al siguiente código:

```
printf("La suma de los numeros es: %i", sum);
```

Comment: Cabe mencionar que funciona correctamente porque no hay ningún problema con el tiempo de vida de las variables. El literal probablemente está en la sección `.data` del programa.

Comment: Pensé hacerlo así pero el profesor quiere que lo ponga dentro de una función, pero gracias eh, no sabia eso sobre el puntero